# How to send bulk mail with java spring email best practices

Tags: java, spring, email, gmail

I want to send 2000 emails in the same hour. I'm doing this with spring mail and google smtp.But google says you can send me 100 emails in 1 hour.

I couldn't find anything about limit increase.Is there a way to do this?

Or is there another solution you can suggest as best practices?

Answer (score 0):

Google email has built-in limits for emails sent. These limits are server-side and not-client side, so they are immutable. If you want to send over 100 emails an hour, you need to create a custom email domain.